# getting data from child window

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I an working on a project and has encountered a problem. please view the following code.

```
<iframe name="stus" id="stus" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form name="water" id="water" method="post"  autocomplete="off" action="components/com_pocketsea/assets/new/water.php" target="stus">
<input type="hidden" id="newwatermark" name="newwatermark">
</form>  
<div id="posting"></div>
```

and the code for water.php is

```
<?php
$newwat = $_POST['newwatermark'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#posting", window.parent.document).html("<?php echo $newwat; ?>").fadeIn('slow');

 });

</script>
```

plz help

Comment: It seems you have forgotten to **tell us what the problem is.**

Answer (score 0):

In your child window, your window object has a property called `opener` which points to the window object of the window that opened it. So when you want to insert data entered into a form in the child window into the page of the parent window, you would do:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    opener.document.getElementById('namearea').innerHTML = document.getElementById('nameform').value;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you want (you did not specified), but I would change my Js code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#posting').html($newwat).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: That will not work, because "$newwat" is a **php** variable, not a JavaScript variable.