# Getting data from a child window

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, parent-child

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting data from child window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278032/getting-data-from-child-window)

I am working on a project and have encountered a problem. Please view the following code.

```
<iframe name="stus" id="stus" style="display:none;"></iframe><div id="posting"></div>

<form name="water" id="water" method="post"  autocomplete="off" action="components/com_pocketsea/assets/new/water.php" target="stus">
<input text="text" id="newwatermark" name="newwatermark"><input type="submit"></form>
```

The code for water.php is

```
<?php $tt = $_POST['newwatermark'];  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js2/jquery.min.js" ></script>  
    <script>        $(document).ready(function(){ $("#posting", window.parent.document).html("<?php echo $tt; ?>").fadeIn('slow'); }); </script>
```

The script is not working. Water.php is not being loaded in parent. This works well in custom but not in joomla. plz help.

Comment: Please do not duplicate your own questions. You will only see downvotes and loosing friends.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `opener` method to access parent window element...

```
 $('#myform').submit(function(){     
       opener.document.getElementById('parentWindowElem').innerHTML = document.getElementById ('childWindowElem').value;    
});
```